# Beautiful Soup - Extraction of attribute's value doesn't work

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, tags

I am trying to get the value of the attribute "data-o" in the following line of code :

`<td class="bc bs oi" data-odig="2.55" data-o="17/11" data-hcap="">17/11</td>`

Here is my code (I refer to an URL in which there is the td tag above)

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.oddschecker.com/football/champions-
league/bayern-munich-v-paris-st-germain/winner')

soup = BeautifulSoup(x.read())

alltd = soup.find_all('td')

for n in alltd:
    print(n['data-o'])
```

I always get an error message...
Some help please ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: What error message do you get? We can't help with error messages if you don't tell us what error message it is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `class` tag is unique to the `'data-o'` items that you want, you may want to use the syntax `{'class': 'class_name'}` to get *only* those `<td>` tags that contain `class='bc bs oi'` first, then print the `'data-o'` item for each of those items.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

x = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.oddschecker.com/football/champions-
league/bayern-munich-v-paris-st-germain/winner')

soup = BeautifulSoup(x.read(), 'html.parser')

alltd = soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'bc bs oi'})

for item in alltd:
    print item['data-o']
```

output:

```
6/4
17/11
13/8
23/10
```

or if you just want the `list`:

```
print [str(item['data-o']) for item in alltd]
['6/4', '17/11', '13/8', '23/10']
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: should `print item['data-o']` be `print (item['data-o'])`?

Comment: @JasonGoal yes, good catch, for python3 it needs to be passed as a function to `print`. thanks for pointing that out.